# Magento Rest API - Empty / blank Order ID returned on successful order creation

Tags: php, rest, magento2, magento-2.3

**Magento Version 2.3**

We are calling Rest API from our PHP code to create orders in Magento  for specific customers and not guest carts. We are able to successfully create orders in Magento (able to see orders in Admin panel with correct order ids) but the api call for http://www.oursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/carts/568/orders (568 is cart id) returns []. We need to the order Id to store in our database for reference and further actions.

I made the API calls using Postman as well and was returning empty order id on successful order creation in Magento. Here are the steps / API calls we made

1) Get Token
2) Get cart Id by passing customer id
3) Add items to cart
4) Add billing address
5) Add shipping address & shipment method
6) Add payment method and create order

**Request Payload:**
{
    "paymentMethod":{
        "method":"purchaseorder",
        "po_number":"00135847520"
    }
}

**Response Payload:** "[]"

The expected result of order ID is not returned . But when we check in magento admin panel, the order is created

Comment: Got this exact same issue. Which sub-version of Magento were you using ? Ours is 2.3.4